# Automatically Mounting internal HDD on 12.04

Tags: mount

I am wondering if all I need to do is add the disks to the fstab (Ubuntu 12.04LTS desktop)
They are both 1 TB internal hard drives
  This site has my text going bold like crazy \ formatting

using `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` to get into the file to modify what drives mount on the boot

original fstab

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
UUID=77d01510-9a51-4818-850c-da05654442f7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

UUID=43ebb068-1983-45a4-b2b7-303caec17d16 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

The changed being

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
UUID=77d01510-9a51-4818-850c-da05654442f7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

UUID=43ebb068-1983-45a4-b2b7-303caec17d16 none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID=77d01510-9a51-4818-850c-da05654442f7 /media/1.0Ubuntu ext4 defaults 0 1

UUID=7CB810DBB810962C /media/New Volume ntfs default 0 1
```

UUID from blkid and mount pt from disk utility
in case anyone is using this.  dump is for archiving so I left at 0 and pass is a disk check (found on wikipedia) so i put 2 so it checks after the root.  defaults was just to fill the options.

Comment: This is a forum and there is no need to add "[Solved]" to the title. Looking carefully at question listings, you can see what questions are solved.

Comment: If there is further info to add on how it was "solved" please add as an answer, or edit the "accepted" answer to include additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automounting at boot is a question of modifying the fstab file.

My experience with Precise is that you may use the UUID but the drive gets two entries in Nautilus devices list. When I changed to /dev/sdb* it worked flawlessly.

Comment: yeah i am getting the 2 device entries now.  I will try that out.  also needed to put \040 for any spaces in the device names or it wont boot with out pressing S

Comment: I clicked it for the answer but can not upvote until i get 15 posts.  Might be able to get back to it

Comment: Yes you're right. But you accepted it as the best answer. That is just as good if not better.

Answer (score 2):

for the 'options' field, use defaults with an s instead of the singular.  It took me some time to figure that out, now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

So I looking for the same answer only based on udisks? I've found that possible do it in opensuse like this

```
touch /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount-system-internal.pkla
```

insert in it

```
[org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount-system-internal]
Identity=unix-group:*
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount-system-internal
ResultAny=auth_admin
ResultInactive=auth_admin
ResultActive=yes
```

Is any possibility that this will working for ubuntu and have that by default. Because if it will presented by default no question about internal mounting appear. fstab not really good for additional drives nor flexible. I think it must contain only system important records.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question all you need to do is edit the fstab file by typing `sudo -i gedit /etc/fstab` in the terminal.

Currently Linex prefers the use of the UUID in the fstab file because the sd*# device assignments can change under certain circumstances between system boots resulting in failed mount attempts.

To fine the UUID for the drive you want to mount type `sudo blkid` in the terminal.

To check if you were successful type `sudo mount -a` in the terminal to remount the disk.